# Uncaught TypeError: cannot call method 'cookie' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Please help!!! I am trying to set this cookie but it is not working. I get an error message that says "Uncaught TypeError: cannot call method 'cookie' of undefined". I dont know why it is saying this. I had this before i added a path and domain so i know that is not what is causing the problem.

my code is

```
<script src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict();
//<![CDATA[

var word = "hello";


var cook = $.cookie("newAr", "word", {expires: 3, path: '/', domain: 'http://localhost/test.html'});

$.cookie("newAr");
document.write("step 1");

//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: `$` is undefined.. The error is clear enough. `$` is initially `undefined` and `$.noConflict()` returns it to that state.

Comment: P.S: `document.write` is bad practice in some cases. Better use `innerHTML` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `$` to access jquery methods after you have said this

```
$.noConflict();
```

Remove this statement. It means there is someone else(library) other than jquery using the $` symbol and I see in your case there is nothing like that.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to perform the jQuery code without conflict is

```
(function($){
    var word = "hello";
    var cook = $.cookie("newAr", "word", {expires: 3, path: '/', domain: 'http://localhost/test.html'});
    $.cookie("newAr");
    document.write("step 1");
})(jQuery);
```